# Android NFC Coupon application terminated unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, api, sharedpreferences, nfc

Thanks to the replies on NFC and a few certain things, I've understood and managed to compile a code in which the users will be able to read a tag, and if the tag contains a string that is similar to my code, a coupon will be added (image changes) and an integer goes up by 1. This integer will be saved by SharedPreferences and it is used to determine how many coupons the users have collected and show it onResume.

However, after compiling, when I try to run it, my application stops immediately. Can someone help me check on what I may have go wrong? I know it's kinda long but I really have no idea what went wrong.

```
@TargetApi(10)    
//I have to use this line of code because I'm targetted to code at API 8 but some NFC functionalities that I use requires API 10.

public class CouponManager extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = "NFCReadTag";
        private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
        private IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;
        private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;
        public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";

        private int[] images = new int[10];

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.coupon_layout);

            //List of images
            images[0]=R.drawable.cp0;
            images[1]=R.drawable.cp1;
            images[2]=R.drawable.cp2;
            images[3]=R.drawable.cp3;
            images[4]=R.drawable.cp4;
            images[5]=R.drawable.cp5;
            images[6]=R.drawable.cp6;
            images[7]=R.drawable.cp7;
            images[8]=R.drawable.cp8;
            images[9]=R.drawable.cp9;
            images[10]=R.drawable.cp10;

            //Restore preferences 
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

            //Image to use depending on coupon collected
            final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

            if(storedPreference!=10)
            {
                img.setImageResource(images[storedPreference]);
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Redeem Your Coupon?");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putInt("storedInt", 0); // value to store
                        editor.commit();    
                        img.setImageResource(images[0]);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        img.setImageResource(images[10]);
                    }
                });
            }


            //Check and send Intent from NFC tag discovered
            mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

            mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), 0);


            IntentFilter coupontag = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
            coupontag.addDataScheme("http");
            coupontag.addDataAuthority("www.ichatime.com", null);
            coupontag.addDataPath(".*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);

            mNdefExchangeFilters = new IntentFilter[] { coupontag };

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(mNfcAdapter != null) {
                mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent,
                    mNdefExchangeFilters, null);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, No NFC Adapter found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(mNfcAdapter != null) mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
              // All objects are from android.context.Context
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
                editor.commit();    
        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);      
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);

            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                NdefMessage[] messages = null;
                Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                    messages = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                    }
                }
                if(messages[0] != null) {
                    String result="";
                    byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
                    // this assumes that we get back am SOH followed by host/code
                    for (int b = 1; b<payload.length; b++) { // skip SOH
                        result += (char) payload[b];
                    }
                    if (result == "ichatime.com")
                        {
                        final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coupon collected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (storedPreference!=10)
                        {
                            storedPreference++;
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference);
                            img.setImageResource(images[storedPreference]);
                        }
                            if (storedPreference==10)
                            {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                builder.setCancelable(false);
                                builder.setTitle("Redeem Your Coupon?");
                                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                    {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                        editor.putInt("storedInt", 0); // value to store
                                        editor.commit();    
                                        img.setImageResource(images[0]);
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        img.setImageResource(images[10]);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putInt("storedInt", 10);
                            img.setImageResource(images[10]);
                        }}
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong tag detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //Debugging Mode to see what is contained in the tags.
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tag Contains " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Logcat errors:

```
>11-26 01:16:11.869: D/AndroidRuntime(550): Shutting down VM
>
11-26 01:16:11.869: W/dalvikvm(550): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
>
11-26 01:16:11.929: I/dalvikvm(550): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
**11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ponpon/com.example.ponpon.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ponpon/com.example.ponpon.CouponManager}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10**
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ponpon/com.example.ponpon.CouponManager}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1797)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.example.ponpon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  ... 11 more
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at com.example.ponpon.CouponManager.onCreate(CouponManager.java:53)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>
11-26 01:16:11.979: E/AndroidRuntime(550):  ... 21 more
```

What did I do wrong with my arrays? Thanks for the clarification guys!

Comment: You should always post your logcat errors when your app crashes.

Comment: Posted my LogCat errors. Thanks for the tip!
Seems like I have an arrayoutofbounds error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat is printing an ArrayOutOfBounds exception on your onCreate method.

The problem is that you are declaring a 10 items sized array, and then trying to put 11 items on it.

You have to declare a new int[11] array.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem by adding the array count by 1. What I don't understand is, I want to keep 11 items in the array so isn't

private int[] images = new int[10] enough?

Cause from what I understand, int[0] keeps the first value, hence int[10] will keep the eleventh value? Thank you guys!

Comment: Arrays in Java (and most programming languages) are zero based. In the construction you give it the size e.g. `[11]` and then you can index it by using `[0]` to `[10]`. This fits nicely with the arithmetic modulo function e.g. `11 % 11 == 0`. Visual basic was 1 based, but this changed when they added it to the .NET spectrum.